# unable to compare strings in mongodb collection

Tags: string, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm a beginner in mongodb and pymongo and I have a mongodb movie database where I store the users 
with fields(name,surname,email,category).I am trying to insert a user in my mongodb data using a pymongo and the user key must be a string that is either "Admin" or "Simple". However I am a complete beginner and I do not know how to compare a mongodb collection instance with a string .
I have my code down below :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from flask import Flask , request , Response , jsonify , redirect
from pymongo.errors import DuplicateKeyError
import json


client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client['MovieFlixDB']

users = db['Users']
movies = db['Movies']

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/insertuser' , methods = ['POST'])
def insert_user():
    data = None
    try:
       data=json.loads(request.data)
    except Exception as e:
        return Response("Bad json content" , status = 500 , mimetype='application/json') 
    if data==None:
        return Response("no data has been added" , status = 500 , mimetype='application/json')
    if not "name" in data or not "surname" in data or not "email" in data or not "category" in data:
        return Response("Information incompleted" , status = 500 , mimetype='application/json')
    if data['category']!="admin" and data['category']!="simple":
    return Response("Invalid category." ,status = 500 , mimetype='application/json')
```

EDIT : I realised that I cannot compare something that has not been inserted in my database and I actually have to compare data["category"] not users.find(...) and I updated my code

I would appreciate your help with this task . Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the output of `users.find({"category":data["category"]})`?

Comment: @ngShravil.py It is basically a user with category:admin or category : "simple"

Comment: Are you sure? You mentioned `I store the users with fields(name,surname,email,category)`, then how can `users.find({"category":data["category"]})` retrieve only category, as you have not mentioned the projection parameter. I would recommend you to go through the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/).

Comment: @ngShravil.py Ijust edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use below:

```py
db_data = users.find_one({"email":data["email"]})
if db_data["category"] == data['category']:
    # Do something
else:
    # Do something else
```

I suggest you to use `find_one`, instead of `find`, since you need to find only one document, matching the condition.